# Error using @Nuxt.js/Cloudinary module for Media Optimization "You don't have sufficient permissions to access this endpoint"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, cloudinary

I'm using [@nuxtjs/cloudinary module](https://cloudinary.nuxtjs.org/) as described in the module guide and following a course video, but I keep getting this error on the response
`Status 403, message:You don't have sufficient permissions to access this endpoint"`

My cloudinary account is using Media Optimizer. Cloud name, API and Secret keys are installed correctly. After some search I found out that the module is based on Programmable Media product and not Media Optimizer and there's a different api end points for that. However, the course video is usinng the media optimizer product and the same module and it works! I chceked the docs and tried to make it work anyways but i couldn't. The course is [Mastering Nuxt](https://masteringnuxt.com/) if it helps.

`ImageUploader.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="file" accept=".jpeg,.gpj,image/jpeg" @change="uploadFile" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { unWrap } from "~/utils/fetchUtils";
export default {
  methods: {
    async uploadFile(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0];

      /* Make sure file exists */
      if (!file) return;

      /* Creating the cloudinary options object */
      const filename = file.name.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".") + Date.now();
      const options = { timestamp: Date.now(), public_id: filename };

      /* Create a signature */
      const response = await unWrap(
        await fetch("/api/cloudinary/signature", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(options),
        })
      );
      const signature = response.data.signature;

      /* Create a reader */
      const readData = (fileObj) =>
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
          reader.readAsDataURL(fileObj);
        });
      const data = await readData(file);

      /* upload the converted data */
      console.log(signature); // for testing
      const asset = await this.$cloudinary.upload(data, {
        ...options,
        apiKey: this.$config.cloudinary.apiKey,
        signature,
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

`nuxt.config`

```
modules: [
  "@nuxtjs/firebase",
  "~/modules/cloudinary",
]

publicRuntimeConfig: {
  cloudinary: {
    apiKey: "399741578529427",
  },
},

privateRuntimeConfig: {
  cloudinary: {
    apiSecret: "<My-Secret-API-Key>",
  },
},

cloudinary: {
  cloudName: "nuxtbnb-m98",
},
```

`modules/cloudinray.js`

```
import { createHash } from "crypto";

export default function () {
  const config = this.options.privateRuntimeConfig.cloudinary;

  this.nuxt.hook("render:setupMiddleware", (app) => {
    app.use("/api/cloudinary/signature", setSignature);
  });

  function setSignature(req, res) {
    try {
      const sha1 = createHash("sha1");
      const payload = [];

      Object.keys(req.body).forEach((key) => {
        payload.push(`${key}=${req.body[key]}`);
      });

      sha1.update(payload.sort().join("&") + config.apiSecret);
      const signature = sha1.digest("hex");

      res.end(
        JSON.stringify({
          signature,
        })
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading assets is only possible with a Programmable Media account. The course is a paid course so I can't access its content but I'd recommend:

- create a new Programmable Media account with another email address.
- or contact support@cloudinary.com so we can assist in deleting the current account to free up your email address.

Comment: So I have to use a Programmable Media account or implement the functionality i want manually not using the module?